# Not answering when you close the program

Tags: java, for-loop, progress-bar, sleep

I have a progress bar made by fillrect(), drawrect() and thread.sleep(). The problem is that when I want to close the program or resize the frame, the progress bar stops and the program doesn't respond. I am looking for an alternative way to do this progress bar without using the JPregressBar() and if I press close the Frame closes.
This is the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame{

private int num1, num2, width=0, g1;

public Main(){
    this.setTitle("Progressbar with rectangles");
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(true);
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawRect(40, 40, 300, 20);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    for(width=0; width<300; width++){   
        g.fillRect(40,40,width,20);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}



public static void main(String[]args){
    Main m=new Main();
}
}
```

Comment: @Vogel612, thanks for the heads up. I'm going to remove my comment!

Comment: I did find this link that may be of use to the asker: http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/05/interruptedexception-and-interrupting.html

Comment: You shouldn't call `Thread.sleep` on the Event Dispatch Thread (in the `paint` method). You should also be calling `super.paint(g)` to allow the painting behavior that you're currently overriding to perform. Lastly, you should be painting via a `JPanel` using `paintComponent`, not a window. I recommend checking out [The Java Tutorial - Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is, that you sleep in the Eventdispatching Thread.

You have to do your work in a new Thread.

The secound problem. You should call the superMethod from paint.

And everytime you want to repaint. Call repaint() :)

```
private int num1, num2, width = 0, g1;

public Main() {
    this.setTitle("Progressbar with rectangles");
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(true);

    Main main  = this;

    Thread t = new Thread( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            for(width=0; width<300; width++) {

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        main.repaint();
                    }
                });


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    });

    t.start();
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawRect(40, 40, 300, 20);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    g.fillRect(40, 40, width, 20);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I can close the program but the repaint doesn't work well, we can not see the progress bar. How can I do to do a good repaint?